# SQL Server : Alter View error - no column name specified

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to alter a view - I am just trying to provide a complete new definition of the `SELECT` statement that runs.

My SQL statement looks like this (I've changed some cols for privacy reasons):

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.vwViewNameHere
AS
   SELECT 
       h.BATCH, h.batch_name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,  
       h.serial_from, h.serial_to, h.batch_description
   FROM            
       (SELECT 
            BATCH, LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS batch_name, 
            aa AS serial_from, bb AS serial_to, 
            CONVERT(varchar(99), BATCH) + ' - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS batch_description
        FROM 
            [IPAddress].database.dbo.tablename) AS h 
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.othertablename AS b WITH (nolock) ON LTRIM(RTRIM(b.Batch_Name)) = h.batch_name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS 
                                              AND h.serial_from = b.Start_Serial 
                                              AND h.serial_to = b.End_Serial
    WHERE 
        (b.Batch_ID IS NULL)
```

I've confirmed that the select runs correctly but when I run the alter view statement I get back a message:

> Msg 4511, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwViewNameHere_NotImportedyet, Line 3
>   Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 2.

I ran a `CREATE VIEW` statement to take a backup of this view definition previously and it created with no error.

Comment: 3rd line h.batch_name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS As batch_name

Comment: Thanks to all three of you for spotting this! I assumed that the query would carry through the column name in spite of the `COLLATE` but apparently not - makes sense I suppose as it does technically alter the column content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify a name for column 2, exactly as the message says. Specify a name:

```
h.batch_name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as batch_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error message:

> Msg 4511, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwViewNameHere_NotImportedyet, Line 3
>   Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 2.

Could you just try:

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.vwViewNameHere
AS
   SELECT 
       h.BATCH, h.batch_name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as batch_name,  
-- etc
```